# Como obtengo el valor mínimo en un array C# si este no está completamente lleno de valores, por ende tendría ceros y me retornaría 0 como valor mínimo

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

tengo un array con una dimensión de 5, pero si pongo numeros sin llenar el array, los espacios que sobran quedan en 0. Estoy queriendo obtener el mínimo valor y siempre me marca 0 porque no está completamente lleno, hay alguna forma de filtrar esos 0?.

```
int[] numeros = new int[5];
for (int i = 0; i < numeros.Length; i++)
{
    numeros[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
Console.WriteLine();

    minimo = numeros.Min();
    maximo = numeros.Max();
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciertamente te llenará de ceros porque el valor default de un `int` es cero. El problema de filtrar los ceros como tu indicas, es que cero sigue siendo un valor posible para un entero, es decir también filtrarías los ceros cuando es ingresado por el usuario

Para tu caso, puede ser mejor usar un *nulleable* int `int?` (con el signo ? al final), en este caso el valor default será `null`

```
int?[] numeros = new int?[5];
         
Console.WriteLine(numeros.Min()); //null
Console.WriteLine(numeros.Max()); //null

numeros[2] = 2;
Console.WriteLine(numeros.Min()); //2
Console.WriteLine(numeros.Max()); //2

numeros[1] = 3;
Console.WriteLine(numeros.Min()); //2
Console.WriteLine(numeros.Max()); //3
```

Ahora que trabajas con valores nulos es muy importante validar cuando lo sean.

```
int?[] numeros = new int?[5];

var minimo = numeros.Min();
var maximo = numeros.Max();

if(minimo is not null && maximo is not null)
{
    //Aquí puedo trabar de forma segura con "minimo" y "maximo"

    //Puedes convertirlo a un int normal si lo prefieres
    int minInt = minimo.Value;
    int maxInt = maximo.Value;
}
```

---

Pero para no dejar de responder tu pregunta especifica sobre filtrar datos: Para filtrar usas un `Where`

```
int[] numeros = new int[5];

//Etc..

int[] numeros_sin_ceros =  numeros.Where(a => a != 0).ToArray();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, me sirvió (aunque no sea el lugar para decirlo).